# How to crawl IEEE

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I am working on the project that needs to crawl IEEE website.
I use BeautifulSoup to perform this.
Here is my code:

```
import bs4 as bs
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets import QWebPage

class Client(QWebPage):
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        QWebPage.__init__(self)
        self.loadFinished.connect(self.on_page_load) 
        self.mainFrame().load(QUrl(url))
        self.app.exec_()

    def on_page_load(self):
        self.app.quit() 

url = 'https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/Xplore/home.jsp'
client_response = Client(url)
source = client_response.mainFrame().toHtml() # capture what browser show
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
for e in soup.find('div'):
    print(e.text)
```

However, after I execute this set of codes, the console shows that it's running
but there is nothing responding back to me (Now, the console is still running).

Can you help me fix this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If I use `requests` (by import requests) to get http response, the program works. So the issue is not with beautiful soup, but with PyQt5 package. I never use PyQt5 before so can't comment where the problem is. Not sure why you using it, but `requests` package seems to be much straightforward and simple to use.

Comment: I use the PyQt to mimics the web browser and make the website load all content firstly. I think that, if the content generating/loading is finished, I can then crawl the javascript-generated content.